# Complex validation extension

Tags: c#, validation, generics, fluentvalidation

While writing extensions for Fluent Validation rule builder I came up with the idea to make more complex validation and then wire it with client validation. I've successfully created extensions that validate one property based on another and so on. What I am struggling with is the validation on multiple fields:

The extension method as on https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom&referringTitle=Documentation

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> Required<T, TProperty>(this IRuleBuilder<T, TProperty> ruleBuilder, Action<MyRuleBuilder<T>> configurator)
    {
        MyRuleBuilder<T> builder = new MyRuleBuilder<T>();

        configurator(builder);

        return ruleBuilder.SetValidator(new MyValidator<T>(builder));
    }
```

The MyRuleBuilder class which allows adding rules fluently:

```
public class MyRuleBuilder<T>
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Rules = new Dictionary<string,object>();

    public MyRuleBuilder<T> If(Expression<Func<T, object>> exp, object value)
    {
        Rules.Add(exp.GetMember().Name, value);

        return this;
    }
}
```

Then the view model and view model validator rules look like this:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public bool DeviceReadAccess { get; set; }
    public string DeviceReadWriteAccess { get; set; }
    public int DeviceEncrypted { get ; set; }
}

RuleFor(x => x.HasAgreedToTerms)
    .Required(builder => builder
        .If(x => x.DeviceReadAccess, true)
        .If(x => x.DeviceReadWriteAccess, "yes")
        .If(x => x.DeviceEncrypted, 1 ));
```

**The problem:**

The above works fine but what I don't like is the "If" function. it does not enforce the value to be of the selected property type. Example:

```
RuleFor(x => x.HasAgreedToTerms)
    .Required(builder => builder
        .If(x => x.DeviceReadAccess, true) // I would like the value to be enforced to bool
        .If(x => x.DeviceReadWriteAccess, "yes") // I would like the value to be enforced to string

// Ideally something like 

// public MyRuleBuilder<T> If(Expression<Func<T, U>> exp, U value) but unfortunately U cannot be automatically inferred
```

Is it possible with this architecture or should i take a different approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add another generic paramter `U` to the method.

```
public class MyRuleBuilder<T>
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Rules = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public MyRuleBuilder<T> If<U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> exp, U value)
    {
        Rules.Add(exp.GetMember().Name, value);

        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case T would be TestViewModel type and U would be of what type? Remember that there is an Action delegate in Required extension function which has MyRuleBuilder<T>. What would you pass as U here?

Comment: @Zanuff You are right...you have to add another generic parameter to the Interface as well...the parameter will change you will have to pass `Action<MyRuleBuilder<T,U>`, I'm not sure if you can do that...

Comment: @Zanuff I didnt realized I didn't added the generic parameter to the method....check my edit.

Comment: I've rewritten my method just like in your answer 30 mins ago and it seems to be the thing that I've wanted to achieve. Guess I am lacking some knowledge in Generics. Need to improve that :) Anyway this seems to be a correct answer. Thanks for your help.